# In Javascript event.key not returning keypresses for hangul characters in console.log

Tags: javascript, keystroke

I have been having trouble with Hangul (KO) character input on an html5 webpage that uses Ajax. console.log will not log the keystrokes for Hangul, but it will log English keystrokes. The code that is supposed to show what I type is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('userText').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

  console.log('410-Key pressed: ', event.key);

.... lot's of other code
}
```

How can I get the key events for Hangul characters instead of just the word 'process'?

This problem occurs on both Firefox and chrome browsers on the desktop.

The `<html lang="ko">` tag is present.

The typing is taking place in an element of type textarea
`<textarea id="userText" lang="KO"></textarea>`.

This is part of a larger problem where, on android mobile devices, the initial Hangul character typed is shown as the individual key-presses while subsequent Hangul characters are properly assembled and shown as syllable characters.

I was expecting to see the character typed, whether English or Korean. In the case of Korean I was expecting to see the individual vowels and consonant characters and then the syllable character.

Comment: You might have better luck catching the "input" event and examining `event.data` instead of `event.key`.

Comment: input doesn't work with textarea elements. When working with English event.key gives, for example, "m" when the "m" key is pressed. When processing Hangul, to make the syllable "검" the keys "ㄱ", "ㅓ" and "ㅁ" have to be pressed in order. What should appear on the screen is: "ㄱ". "거" "검" in that order. The browser has to assemble the three characters typed to get the final "검". But when typing Hangul (Korean), the event.key just returns process until the syllable is complete and it goes on to the next syllable.

Comment: What appears to be happening is that on a PC browser event.key reports a process instead of a key when entering text in a textarea element, but on a mobile device for the first syllable the actual Hangul keys typed are returned. After the first syllable on a mobile the syllable is returned.

Comment: I set up debugging on an Android device and it also is reporting "process" for Hangul keystrokes regardless of whether individual characters are rendering or an entire syllable. 

keycode = 229 is being reported for any Hangul input.

Comment: If using IME (Input Method Editor), you probably want to listen to `compositionstart`, `compositionupdate` and/or `compositionend` events. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/compositionstart_event)